# Can a .bat Script Copy Marked Text From One File to A Marked Location in Another File?

Tags: batch-file

In the source file I have:

```
...
<!-- MARK_BEGIN -->
some text line 1
some text line 2
...
<!-- MARK_END -->
...
```

that I want to copy the above marked content, without the begin/end marks, into a destination file, either at the very beginning, the very end, or at a location marked as:

```
...
<!-- INSERT_HERE -->
...
```

The command would be:

```
copyMarkedContent.bat sourceFile destFile [TOP | BOTTOM | MARKED ]
```

The **sourceFile** is guaranteed to have the lines containing **MARK_BEGIN** and **MARK_END** in them.  The **destFile** is guaranteed to have the line containing **INSERT_HERE** if the **MARKED** argument is given to the **copyMarkedConent.bat** command.

Is there a way to do this with a .bat script on Windows (Windows 7 or Windows 2008) using just those facilities that come with the OS?

Comment: Is there a way to do this?  Yes, with for loops.  [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: did you consider using PowerShell? Or is this an option?

Comment: @user503413 - My understanding is that PowerShell is included with Windows Server 2008, but it needs to be installed.  This makes it a non-option for my purposes because I am constrained to use only what is installed and available with standard Windows 7 and Windows 2008 operating systems.  If I could install additional software, I could make this much easier by using any one of a number of programming languages well suited for text manipulation.  But, as it is, I'm confronted with the daunting task of determining whether .bat scripts can do the job.  What a challenge!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think it'll do what you are looking for.  If there's an error in it, at least it'll get you started.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if #%3==# goto usage

:: convert %3 to upper case
for /f "tokens=5" %%I in ('find "" "%3" 2^>^&1') do set arg=%%I
for %%I in (TOP BOTTOM MARKED) do (if "%arg%"=="%%I" goto next)

:usage
echo usage: %~nx0 sourceFile destFile [TOP^|BOTTOM^|MARKED]
goto :EOF

:next
set /p I="Scraping data from %1... "<NUL
set tempfile=~%time::=%.txt
set tempfile=%tempfile: =%
set tag=0
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%H in ('findstr /n ".*" %1') do (
    if not "%%J"=="" (set line=%%I:%%J) else (set line=%%I)
    if !tag!==1 (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('echo "!line!" ^| find /i "<!-- mark"') do (
            echo Done.
            goto %arg%
        )
        if "!line!"=="" (echo;>>%tempfile%) else (echo !line!>>%tempfile%)
    )
    for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('echo "!line!" ^| find /i "<!-- mark"') do set tag=1
)

:TOP
set /p I="Prepending data to %2... "<NUL
type %2>>%tempfile%
move /y %tempfile% %2 >NUL
echo Done.
goto :EOF

:BOTTOM
set /p I="Appending data to %2... "<NUL
type %tempfile%>>%2
del /q %tempfile%
echo Done.
goto :EOF

:MARKED
set /p I="Inserting data into %2... "<NUL
set tag=0
set tempfile2=~%time::=%_2.txt
set tempfile2=%tempfile2: =%
for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %%H in ('findstr /n ".*" %2') do (
    if not "%%J"=="" (set line=%%I:%%J) else (set line=%%I)
    if "!line!"=="" (echo;>>%tempfile2%) else (echo !line!>>%tempfile2%)
    if !tag!==0 (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('echo "!line!" ^| find /i "<!-- insert"') do (
            set tag=1
            type %tempfile%>>%tempfile2%
            del /q %tempfile%
        )
    )
)
move /y %tempfile2% %2 >NUL
echo Done.
```

**EDIT 1 :** I made the checks for `<!-- MARK` and `<!-- INSERT` case insensitive and not dependent on having no spaces before.

**EDIT 2 :** I broke down and actually started testing my changes.  I made a few changes to ensure that indentation and other formatting gets preserved, and the script tests successfully on my Win 7 machine.

Comment: I'll test this asap and let everyone know if I need to make any changes!  Kudos!

Comment: I found a problem where content in the file contains special characters, resulting in an error message: "The system cannot find the file specified."  For example, on the line:

for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('echo %%I ^| find /i "<!-- mark"') do (

The %%I gets expanded to:

<!-- MARK_BEGIN -->

But, this results in the above error.  This can be shown more simply just by doing:

C:\> echo '<!-- MARK_BEGIN -->'
The system cannot find the file specified.

Is there a solution to escape the %%I content so that this error does not happen?

Comment: Does that change need to be in the source file?  I think the content of %%I is being expanded and this is what is causing the problem. I commented out the @echo off and see in the output:

`for /F "tokens=*" %x in ('echo <!-- MARK_BEGIN --> | find /i "<!-- mark"') do set tag=1
)
The system cannot find the file specified.`

So, it seems that some kind of Escape(%%I) is needed, right?  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Changing `echo %%I` to `echo "%%I"` in the `for` loops fixed what you described.  Delayed expansion in echos out to the destfile also prevents evaluation of less-than, greater-than, pipes, etc.  I tested the script and I believe it works as you want it to now.  Enjoy.

Comment: How can I ever thank you?!  Your code not only works, but is a jumping off point for showing people how bat scripts can do a lot more than most anyone could have imagined!  Many, many thanks!!